How can I check if a key exists in data of text template in Go?
I want to check if a key exists (not existing != zero value) in the data passed to the template.Exec function. Using {{if or {{with works but only if value of the key is not the zero value.
{{if .Num}} evaluates to false when Num (int) exists but its value is 0.

AFAICT there isn't anything built in that checks for the absence of map keys, so your only option would be to declare and register a custom function and use that.
